# Dynamodb get about 10,000 t0 30,000 records nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

```
getDBResults(id,
startDate_Timestamp,
endDate_Timestamp).then(data, 
err)=>  {
if (err) console.log("EE", err);
console.log("DD",data);
if (data.length != 0) {
 res.json({ "Status": 200, "Data": data });
 }
 })

 function getDBResults(id, startDate_Timestamp, 
 endDate_Timestamp) {
 var q = Q.defer();
 const params = {
 TableName: 'TableName',
 KeyConditionExpression: '#Id=:Id AND #Timestamp BETWEEN  
:start_date AND :end_date',
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
  "#Timestamp": "Timestamp",
  "#Id": "Id"
},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ":Id": id,
  ":start_date": startDate_Timestamp,
  ":end_date": endDate_Timestamp
}
};
var results = [];
var callback = function (err, data) {
console.log("DD", data);
if (err) {
  console.log('Dynamo fail ' + err);
  q.reject(err);
} else if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
  params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
  docclient.query(params, callback);
} else {
  console.log("RR",results);
  q.resolve(results);
}
data.Items.forEach(function (item) {
  results.push(item);
});
}
docclient.query(params, callback);
return q.promise;
}
```

with this code, i am not getting any results and result of that 
  id contains almost 20,000 to 30,000 records. I want to fetch all 
  that records but it does not log anything on aws console.Please 
  help me to figure it out

Comment: It will help cleaning your code, it is hard to read now. Start by indenting and putting on one line the code that should be on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the solution, but I would try to insert in `results` before calling a new query:

```
} else if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    // save items
    data.Items.forEach(function (item) { results.push(item); });        
    params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
    docclient.query(params, callback);
}
```

Advice: think about using promises, they are easier to work with. Your code is a "callback hell" :)

Comment: Use more. All I see is a `callback` function :)

Comment: can you have any code of promise i want to implement functionality where there will be Foreach where one by one i want to fetch all records and stop the loop till all data of one id comes from dynamodb comes.If you can please help